# Trying to open external application in Browser prevents receiving socket.io emits

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

Lets rewrite my problem:

I will not provide any code because it would cost me too much payed worktime to extract the certain code samples from my project. On top of that i think its not code related, but browser/browser-security related.

When Chrome (Or Edge) tries to open an external application (No matter what application), an alert box pops open that asks if Chrome should open the external application.

Regardless if i open it or cancel the alert box, at this very moment all socket.io communication from my backend server isnt received anymore.

Before trying to open the external application or after a page refresh, everything runs fine.

Thats my problem, i apologise if some may not be able to understand the problem without me providing any code samples. I just hope someone comes by who already had that kind of problem and knows how to fix it.

Comment: A small piece of code is usually more useful than a big chunk of text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to go around this problem. I open my link to the external application directly in a new tab, which transfers the Alert Box to the newly opened tab.

The alert box seemed to have caused the error. When it opens in another tab, my main tab can still receive the backend emits.

Thanks for everyone who stumbled over this^^